# asp.net Tabs style lost and tabs are not generated

Tags: css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

My asp.net web app uses AjaxControlToolkit 3.5, I use TabContainer and there are 4 tabs in it.
For unknown reason the four tabs won't show up as tabs, although their tab's caption are there, and clicking on each caption will take me to the "tab"

What's the possible reason that the tabs fail to show up? css style file lost? or AjaxControlToolkit failed?

Thank you. Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe AjaxControlToolkit is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this where I could switch between tabs and there was no content on them. The root of the problem ended up being missing closing tags in the ContentTemplate of one of the TabPanels. Inspect your html very closely inside of the ContentTemplate to ensure the html is valid and all tags are properly closed.